# Get localStorage array out as an array

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am playing around with HTML5 localStorage but am having some trouble.

I am saving an object array like this:

```
var test = { 0: 'hello', 1: 'what', 2: 'no way', 3: 'yes way' };
localStorage["savedtest"] = JSON.stringify(test);
```

This part is working just fine, but... Now I want to retrieve it and use it as an array, but can't figure out what to do?

Here is what I am trying:

```
var testback = JSON.parse(localStorage["savedtest"]);
var mytest = testback[0];

alert("Here: "+mytest);
```

But it doesn't seem to work... What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I found this to be a great resource in working with localStorage... https://github.com/artberri/jquery-html5storage

Comment: Works flawless for me. What are you doing in between setting and getting?

Comment: I don't suppose you are testing this site by opening a filesystem html page? (ie, your url bar shows "file://c:/pornography/localtest.html")

Comment: SORRYYYYY! Typo from my side... Works just fine :-/

Comment: Its working clean for me make sure you are not clearing localStorage in between

Comment: @Katana314: Why would you have your webpage in your porn folder? ^~^

Comment: @RocketHazmat ...You guys put them someplace else?